# SQL Server Windows Authentication using a Service

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, windows-authentication

I am running a Java Application as a Service in Windows that's using JDBC to connect to SQL Server. This application is started as a different user than the one logged into the Machine. My question is will the JDBC Driver use the user assigned to start the service to authenticate against or the logged in user (which there might not be one)?

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you try it and find out?

Comment: I am researching using Windows Authentication for our next release and I have nothing setup yet to try it. Otherwise I would have. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change logged in users all you want, the service will keep running in the background under the account that it was initially started.

If the connection is set to using Integrated Security, then the account that the service is started under will be the one that is used.

Answer (score 0):

The service will connect using whatever user the service is running under (as visible in the service control manager).

Answer (score 0):

Your service application is configured to always run as a particular user, for example "Service_User".

Even if user "Bob" logs in to start the service - all connections/files made by that service will appear to be from user "Service_User".

In your service application you make a JDBC connection to a database.  If you specify Integrated Security in the connection string, it will log in to the database as "Service_User".

If you specify a Database username / password in your connection string, it will log into the database as that user.

That will happen regardless of the interactive login used to start it on the system.

Comment: My service is started by a different user than the one that logs in. I was wondering about that situation